# Plotting LiDAR data with matplotlib

Tags: python, lidar, las, matplotlib, laspy

I am trying to plot a las file with one million points in Matplotlib. When I try to plot the file it always gives me a blank result.

This is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import laspy
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reading las file and copy points
input_las = laspy.read("C:\\split.las")
point_records = input_las.points.copy()

x_mask_g = np.array(point_records.X)
y_mask_g = np.array(point_records.Y)
z_mask_g = np.array(point_records.Z)

fig_surf_g = plt.figure()
ax = fig_surf_g.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x_mask_g, y_mask_g, z_mask_g)
plt.title("Ground Surface")
```

Comment: The code here may help. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277317/visualizing-las-with-matplotlib?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget the `plt.show()` command at the end?

Comment: No it just gives three dimension axis with no lidar data

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine.
Obvisouly I use random data, so surface has no real elevation meaning.
So, you might check that your input data is correct: data present, no tricky decimal separator, absence of "invalid data", "Not A Number" (NaN) etc.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# import laspy
import pandas as pd

# reading las file and copy points
# input_las = laspy.read("C:\\split.las")
# point_records = input_las.points.copy()

# create fake data since I do not have your data source at hand
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
n = 1_000
df.X = np.random.uniform(low=-45, high=45, size=(n,))
df.Y = np.random.uniform(low=-179, high=180, size=(n,))
df.Z = np.random.uniform(low=-1000, high=9000, size=(n,))

x_mask_g = df.X.to_numpy()
y_mask_g = df.Y.to_numpy()
z_mask_g = df.Z.to_numpy()

fig_surf_g = plt.figure()
ax = fig_surf_g.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x_mask_g, y_mask_g, z_mask_g)
plt.title("Ground Surface")
plt.show()
```